# PDFThumbnailView: Not able to select thumbnails in Sierra for MAC OSx App

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-sierra, pdfview

I am using PDFKit. Please refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Tasks/PDFKit_Prog_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001863-CH202-CHDIADBJ)

`PDFThumbnailView` does not allow to drag or select the thumbnail after I have updated my Mac OS x to Sierra.

Have already set

```
[_pdfThumbnailView setPDFView:_pdfView];
```

and `_pdfThumbnailView` outlet from `xib` too.

If works well for previous OS x version.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Same issue exists in 10.12 beta 7 also :(

Comment: Did you got any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple really screwed PDFKit in MacOS 10.12, among the many other bugs in it, `PDFThumbnailView` is unusable for the most part, it doesn't do anything except displaying a list of pdf pages (with glitches).

I've spent much time into this but I couldn't find any workaround. I'm afraid your options are either waiting for Apple to fix this (hopefully) or rolling out your own thumbnail view replacement.

Creating your own thumbnail view shouldn't be overly complicated. I'd use `NSCollectionView` and render the thumbnails into its grid. Then wire all the selection and drag and drop with the `PDFView`. I'm planning to do exactly this if Apple doesn't fix `PDFThumbnailView` anytime soon.

(ps: there is a nice [tutorial on NSCollectionView](https://www.raywenderlich.com/120494/collection-views-os-x-tutorial) on raywenderlich.com )